gender mismatch?
An excerpt from NVI bible translation:

¡Ay del que dice: “Me edificaré un gran palacio,   con habitaciones
amplias en el piso superior”!Y le abre grandes ventanas,   y la
recubre de cedro y la pinta de rojo.

I'm puzzled by the bolded pronouns.  I would expect palacio or piso to be represented by lo or le and habitaciones or ventanas to be represented by las.

Out of curiosity, what is the English equivalent of that excerpt?  Because I am wondering if your confusion is based around what the actual subject is in each sentence fragment. (and for the record, I'm confused too)

It seems to be a wrong translation of the Bible: https://www.bible.com/es/bible/compare/JER.22.14-16 Notice that where "la" does work is where the place in question is referred to as "una casa", not "un palacio".

A more literal translation of the Hebrew would be large house, so perhaps an earlier draft had "casa" and they changed it to "palacio," forgetting to check the pronouns.

Yes, that seems to have been the case.

@PeterM, it's true that which noun is the subject makes a difference, but "la" doesn't fit any of the nouns.

After seeing comments, I'm guessing the translators revised casa→palacio and failed to change the pronouns.  But that's a guess, and if someone has a better idea, go for it.
Hebrew looks like "large house" so "palace" is reasonable in context.  Other versions:
ESV: great house
KJV: wide house
NIV: great palace
NASB: roomy house
ICL: palazzo grandioso (it)
HTB: prachtig paleis (nl)
NTLH: casa bem grande (pt)

This seems 100% a translation defect

Lo que pasa es que no has entendido el párrafo.

¡Ay del que dice: “Me edificaré un gran palacio,con habitaciones
amplias en el piso superior”!Y le abre grandes ventanas,y la
recubre de cedro y la pinta de rojo.

Inicia explicando que va a construir un palacio con habitaciones en el piso superior, o sea HABITACIONES en la azotea o en el nivel más elevado...

¡Ay del que dice: “Me edificaré un gran palacio,con habitaciones
amplias en el piso superior”!

Despues de eso, ya no habla del palacio o el piso (masculinos), habla de las habitaciones (femenino/as)

Y le abre grandes ventanas,y la
recubre de cedro y la pinta de rojo.

Habla de LAS HABITACIONES, incluso el texto tiene un pequeño "error" ya que tendría que ser en plural y no en singular (aunque desconozco si el error es de copiar y pegar)

Y le abre grandes ventanas,y las
recubre de cedro y las pinta de rojo.

Es decir, a las habitaciones (femenino/as)

In that case, shouldn't the line before have "las" instead of "le"?

@Megustalafruta no presioné bien la barra de espacio "o sea" = "es decir". Gracias por el dato.

@WGroleau en realidad debería ser "les", pero es difícil saber si lo que has puesto es la traducción de un párrafo o el párrafo en si. Para mi que esa "traducción" (sea tuya o del propio libro) esta un poco errada, pero sin ver el texto original es difícil decir más.
